# Loading a component after submitting a form

Tags: reactjs

I tried to load a component to my web app after submitting a form. However, the value doesn't persist on the web page for more than a few seconds.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Load from './load'

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: '',
    showComponent: false,
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this._handleSubmit = this._handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  _handleSubmit(event) {
    //alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    this.setState({
      showComponent: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this._handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
        {this.state.showComponent ?
           <Load /> :
           null
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form
```

The code for Load is as follows

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';


class Load extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <p>hello</p>
    )
  }
}

export default Load
```

As I had said, the value of hello doesn't stay on my screen for more than a few seconds. Please help. I am very new to react

Comment: Did you try calling `preventDefault` in your `handleSubmit` function ?

Comment: if it stays only few seconds it means that after few seconds showComponent isn't anymore `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try preventing default Submit Event of the form this will initiate a GET request and your URL will reload and this will lead to your main component ReRendering and showComponent is being set to false again.

```
  _handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Add this line to prevent your form's default event.

      //alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
      this.setState({
        showComponent: true,
      });
  }
```